# How to make a command available only after another discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a russian roulette bot with discord.py
How do I make the commands "join" and "shoot" available only after someone has started a game using "start"?

Comment: have you tried checking users who sent comands?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that you can't have more than one game at once, so if there are multiple ppl who sent start command it would just be a hot mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make a command available only after other command is used is to create a global variable inside that command and call it in the next command, by this way you are going to get an error if you do not use them in the right order.

**Example:**

```
@commands.command()
async def test(ctx):
    global x
    x = True

@commands.command()
async def test2(ctx):
    print(x)
```

if you use *test2* before *test* you are going to get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

You may use *try except* to solve this

```
@commands.command()
async def start(ctx):
    global game
    game = True

@commands.command()
async def join(ctx):
    try:
        print(game)
    except NameError:
        await ctx.send('There is no game going on')
```

Comment: Ooh thank you good sir! I literally thought of the same thing last night XD

Comment: You are welcome :). I would apreciate a lot if you pick mine as best answer.